# g++: const discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, g++, constants

why do I get a `discard qualifiers` error:

```
customExc.cpp: In member function ‘virtual const char* CustomException::what() const’:
customExc.cpp: error: passing ‘const CustomException’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘char customException::code()’ discards qualifiers
```

on the following code example

```
#include <iostream>


class CustomException: public std::exception {

public:

    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        static std::string msg;
        msg  = "Error: ";
        msg += code();  // <---------- this is the line with the compile error 
        return msg.c_str();
    }

    char code() { return 'F'; }
};
```

I have searched around on SOF before regarding simular issues.

I have already added a `const` on every possible place.

Please enlighten me -  I don't get the point...

**EDIT**:
here are the steps to reproduce on Ubuntu-Carmic-32bit (g++ v4.4.1)

1. save example as `customExc.cpp`
2. type `make customExc.o`

**EDIT**: The error is related to `CustomException`. The class `Foo` has nothing to do with it. So I have deleted it.

Comment: By the way, you should not return `msg.c_str()`, as `msg` is destroyed as soon as `what()` returns - which means that the pointer will not be valid anymore when the user reads it. You may want to consider building it at construction time and storing it as a class member.

Comment: @Raphael: I know. I just wanted to keep the example as simple as possible. And - since the return value of `what()` is `const` - it shouldn't be an issue in practice.

Comment: I don't see what the return value of `what()` being `const` has to do with the safety of returning `msg.c_str()`... it's guaranteed to point to non-existent memory, which is undefined behavior.  don't do that!

Comment: @meador: +1 - you where right!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`CustomException::what` calls `CustomException::code`.  `CustomException::what` is a const method, as signified by the const *after* `what()`.  Since it is a const method, it cannot do anything that may modify itself.  `CustomException::code` is not a const method, which means that it does *not* promise to not modify itself.  So `CustomException::what` can't call `CustomException::code`.

Note that const methods are not necessarily related to const instances.  `Foo::bar` can declare its `exc` variable as non-const and call const methods like `CustomException::what`; this simply means that `CustomException::what` promises not to modify `exc`, but other code might.

The C++ FAQ has a bit more information on [const methods](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10).

Comment: @Josh: Now I got it - and I finally accepted your answer because of the `... what() promises not to modify exc ...`

Answer (score 4):

```
   int code() const { return 42; }
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me. I was putting const before the function name not after.

Answer (score 3):

Your `what()` is a const member function, but `code()` is not.

Just change `code()` to `code() const`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `code()` member function is not declared `const`. Calling non-const member functions from const member functions (`what()` in this case) is illegal.

Make your `code()` member const.

Comment: @meador: A **const** on a method means, that **this** will be a pointer-to-const in this method. If you are aware of that, the error message makes perfect sense: when you try to call `code()` from `what()`, you are trying to convert `(const CustomException*) this` into `(CustomException*)this`, thereby discarding the cv qualifier(s) (**const**)

Comment: I think @rmeador makes a good point. I'm used to that error message, but it could just as easily say "`Cannot call ‘char customException::code()’ from ‘virtual const char* CustomException::what() const’ because ‘char customException::code()’ is not a const member function.`"

Comment: FWIW, Clang gives a nicer error (as is often the case): `test.cpp:11:12: error: member function 'code' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const CustomException', but function is not marked const
    msg += code();  // <---------- this is the line with the compile error
           ^~~~
test.cpp:15:8: note: 'code' declared here
  char code() { return 'F'; }`