# C++ struct - Passing const as this argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, reference, constants

So, I'm trying to make a struct `TileSet` and override the `<` operator, and then put `TileSet`'s in a priority queue. I've read that I can't call non-const methods on a const reference, but there shouldn't really be a problem, I'm just accessing members, not changing them:

```
    struct TileSet
    {

        // ... other struct stuff, the only stuff that matters

        TileSet(const TileSet& copy)
        {
            this->gid = copy.gid;
            this->spacing = copy.spacing;
            this->width = copy.width;
            this->height = copy.height;
            this->texture = copy.texture;
        }

        bool operator<(const TileSet &b)
        {
            return this->gid < b.gid;
        }
    };
```

The error message tells me: passing `'const TileSet' as 'this' argument of 'bool TileSet::operator<(const TileSet&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]` what does this mean? Changing the variables to const did not work, and I need them to be non-const anyways.

The error occurs when I try to do:

`std::priority_queue<be::Object::TileSet> tileset_queue;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ "Passing as this discards qualifiers"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226787/c-passing-as-this-discards-qualifiers)

Comment: I guess you could search google before asking:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226787/c-passing-as-this-discards-qualifiers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973427/error-passing-xxx-as-this-argument-of-xxx-discards-qualifiers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412608/g-const-discards-qualifiers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a `const` qualifier to the definition of `operator<` method:

```
bool operator<(const TileSet &b) const
                               // ^^^ add me
{
    return this->gid < b.gid;
}
```

This tells the compiler that the `this` parameter passed to the function is const, otherwise it will not allow you to pass a const reference as `this` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try making operator< a const member function.